# C++: getline freezes at end of file

Tags: c++, io

I want to read in one file line-by-line and output each line I read to a new file. In this code, cin has been redirected to refer to the input file, and cout has been redirected to refer to the output file.

The loop successfully writes every line in the file, but then it gets stuck on the final getline call. As a result, "Done" is not written to the file and the program does not terminate.

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {

    string line;
    while(getline(cin, line)) {
        cout << line << endl;
    }

    cout << "Done";  

    return 0;
}
```

Strangely, if I forcibly terminate the program, it seems to suddenly execute as desired, with "Done" being written.

Can someone point me in the right direction? Is there a flaw in the code, or is this some external configuration issue?

**Notes:** The input file in question ends with a newline character. Also, I do not want to use any includes besides these two.

Comment: How are you invoking the program?

Comment: I'm actually unable to reproduce the error

Comment: I'm invoking it through the Eclipse IDE.

Comment: I may have mischaracterized the issue. The loop eventually completes, but only when I forcibly terminate the program (which doesn't finish on its own). Does that add anything meaningful?

Comment: Are you invoking it using an interactive mode where you type input? (If so, you can type the terminal EOF character, e.g. ^D, to end the program.) Sometimes programs set up a pty and fail to close the other side for situations like this, but that would be very odd. You can test that by invoking it from a plain shell. Otherwise, I would debug it by printing the length of line and the values of cin.eof() and cin.fail() inside the loop.

Comment: Add a flush to the last output: `std::cout << "Done\n" << std::flush;` I guess, the IDE keeps the window alive or something.

Comment: @ZalmanStern I'm not typing any input. I just set cin to reference a file in the workspace. I tried your recommended debugging and found that the loop executes once for each non-empty line. The lines retrieved are of the correct length. cin.eof() and cin.fail() always return 0.

Comment: @DietmarKühl I got the same result when I added the flush.

Comment: Does it fail to terminate when run from a plain shell as "my_program < input_file"?

Comment: It looks as if the redirection you are using consumes both the file and `std::cin`. Try running the program outside the IDE. It seems you got behavior similar to `cat file - | program` rather than `cat file | program` (or `program < file`).

Comment: It successfully terminates when I run it through the shell! That is a good enough solution for my purposes. If either of you post that as an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code should terminate on end of file (EOF) or any sort of file error. (The getline being called is:
    http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline
It returns the cin istream and then invokes its boolean conversion operator:
    http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ios/ios/operator_bool/
that checks if badbit or failbit is set on the stream. The failbit state should be set when a read is attempted with the stream already at EOF, or if there is an error.)

Per the comments above, it seems like this does work when the code is run from the shell directly. My guess is Eclipse is doing something complicated where it either intentionally sends the file into the program and then switches to an interactive input mode, or has a bug in which it doesn't close its end of a pipe or pty/tty it is using to send input to the program. (I.e. Eclipse is not binding stdin directly to the file itself in running the program.)

If one wanted to debug it further, one could look at the process state using tools like `lsof`. (Assuming a UNIXy system.) Might also be worth raising the issue in an Eclipse forum. The IDE is not my area of expertise.